# FileServer Example - Msg Flow through ChannelHandlers

Tags: java, networking, netty

For the FileServer Example:

The FileServerHandler Sends a String Msg to the client requesting the client to send a file name to retrieve.

The msg flow through the channel pipeline is as follows:

1. FileServerHandler
2. StringEncoder

However, the outbound channel pipeine msg flow as specified in the FileServer is:

1. FileServerHandler
2. chunkedWriteHandler
3. StringEncoder

**Question 1: How & why does the String msg generated from the FileServerHandler skip over the chunkedWriteHandler to the StringEncoder?** What causes the ChunkedWriteHandler to be skipped over? Is this because ChunkedWriteHandler is expecting a ChunkInput and so the handler rejects any msg that is not of type ChunkedInput and passes it on to the next outbound channelHandler which will be the StringEncoder which is expecting a String. if so does the ChunkedWriteHandler automatically ignores the String msg and uses the (context.fireEventType(ev) ) method to push the msg to the StringEncoder

When the fileServerHandler sends the contents of the file, it uses chunkWriteHandler if zero-copy is not allowed on the native machine and therefore the msg flow through the channel pipeline is as follows:

1. FileServerHandler
2. chunkedWriteHandler

**Question 2: How does the data stream generated by chunkedWriteHandler bypass the StringEncoder?** What causes the StringEncoder to be skipped over? I know the StringEncoder is expecting a String to decode to write out to the socket, but how does data stream generated by chunkedWriteHandler bypass the StringEncoder